# Notation for conditional indexed family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Normally, I'd denote by $(S_{i})_{i \in I}$ an indexed family of sets.
What if each $S_{i}$ depends on a variable $x$?
My thought was:
$$
(S_{i} \mid x)_{i \in I}.
$$
Is there a better (more standard) way?

*Edit*:

For example, for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let
$$
S_{i} := \{\, s \in \mathbb{R} \mid (s-i-x)(s-1-i-x) = 0 \,\},
$$
namely $S_{i} = \{\, i+x,1+i+x \,\}$.

(It occurs to me that maybe I should just include the additional variable as part of the index $i$, but I would prefer a conceptual distinction in the role of $x$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $(S_{i} \mid x)_{i \in I}$ is very unusual and I would not recommend it; this is not a standard usage of the symbol $\mid$ in mathematics.  If $x$ is just a constant that is fixed in the background, there is no need to mention it in the notation at all.  If you want to let $x$ vary so you really have a different family $(S_i)_{i\in I}$ for each value of $x$, then what you actually have is a family of sets that are indexed by both $i$ and $x$.  You could write this as $(S_{i,x})$, for instance, or perhaps $(S_i(x))$ or $(S_i^x)$ if you want to make the role of $x$ more visually distinct.  Basically, you can just use any standard notation that is used to denote a family with $x$ as an index (or equivalently, a function of $x$).